# How to add median value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, median

I'm trying a add median to this query below. I already have MAX.and MIN for the Sales_Total_Price Column with the results group by the Item_name.

Can anyone help me. I have seen a lot of posts about this but I am having a hard time attaching that data to my query. thanks!

```
SELECT item_master_list.Item_Name, item_master_list.NPC_Item_Price,
       item_master_list.NPC_Item_Value,   
       MAX(public_vendor_sales_data.Sales_Total_Price),    
       MIN(public_vendor_sales_data.Sales_Total_Price)
FROM item_master_list INNER JOIN
     public_vendor_sales_data
     ON  public_vendor_sales_data.Item_ID = item_master_list.Item_ID
GROUP BY Item_Name
```

---

current results
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gtuH.png)

Comment: group by price, count, order desc, limit 1?

Comment: Are you sure you want the median?  Do you know what that is?

Comment: yes. I know what median is and I know it is hard. That is why I wanted to try and see if I could get some help before I gave up.But yes. I may end up having to use average if I can't solve this problem or try using mode.If I use average and there are some large data on either the low or the high side.That could really skew my number.

Comment: @Daniel . . . I ask because your code doesn't even calculate the average.  That would seem to be a more natural place to start.  Can you explain why you want the median?

Answer (score 0):

I would give up on the median; it is rather hard to calculate.  Instead, I recommend calculating the *average*:

```
SELECT iml.Item_Name, iml.NPC_Item_Price, iml.NPC_Item_Value,   
       MAX(vs.Sales_Total_Price),    
       MIN(vs.Sales_Total_Price),
       AVG(vs.Sales_Total_Price)       
FROM item_master_list iml INNER JOIN
     public_vendor_sales_data vs
     ON vs.Item_ID = iml.Item_ID
GROUP BY Item_Name;
```

Comment: Thank you.I will use this if I can't find the answer for median.